# available php Opening and Closing Tags

Tags: php

PHP [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php#language.basic-syntax.phpmode) states:

```
<%= $variable; # This is a shortcut for "<% echo . . ." %>

<?= expression ?> This is a shortcut for "<? echo expression ?>"
```

> ...short tags and ASP style tags, and can be turned on and off from
>   the php.ini configuration file.

So I attempted to try out the "shortcuts" for ASP style tags and short tags to verify these statements. I got this:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\Users\Robert\Documents\web development\xampp\htdocs\xampp\web_development\new_study\one.php on line 2**

On a simple line of code as this:

```
<%= echo "tom" %>
```

and this

```
<?= echo "tom" ?>
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Take the word echo out, as the = is already doing that

Comment: You are in essence saying `<?php echo echo "tom" ?>`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code should be

```
<%= "tom" %>
```